# Can't mount to the root; read-only

Tags: mount, partition

I'm just about to install operating system (CentOS7.3) through manually setting up the partition. Here I'd like to mount those partitions.

But when I ran the command `mount /dev/sda1 /`, It returns `mount: cannot remount /dev/sda1 read-write, is write-protecte`.

Do you know why it's read-only?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the read-only flag is set in `/etc/fstab`; why this is the case in your installation can't be deducted from the sparse details you gave above.

If you're sure you want to override the RO mount manually you can try

```
# mount -o "remount,rw" /dev/sda1 /
```

Comment: @Mrphy Thanks for the comment. I didn't touch on /etc/fstab but why is it already configure like that? Is that default behavior?

Comment: My crystal ball says no, but if you need a more thorough analysis you'll need to add the significant details to your question, e. g. what you did do to "manually setting up the partition", the output of `mount` and the content of `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: oh ok, and manually setting means that I don't use GUI partition manager but press ctrl + alt + F2 and then `fdisk /dev/sda` and make a partitioning.

Comment: Oh also there's nothing written in /etc/fstab.